# Keyboard is stuck at the GRUB menu

Tags: grub2, keyboard, freeze

Whenever I start my computer, my keyboard does not work in the GRUB menu of Ubuntu 20.08. Ubuntu is at the top and it opens by default. I cannot go to the menus below, as the keyboard does not work (the arrows for scrolling). So, I cannot go to the menus like recovery mode. As a result of this, as I have forgotten my password, I cannot use my Ubuntu OS, as I cannot reset the password without going to those modes.

Comment: Please be precise with details; Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format (with 2000 added to *year*), so you're stating you are using the Ubuntu release from 2020-August (20.08) where no new release came out that month.  Are you using Ubuntu?  if so what release?  What type of keyboard are you using?  as I'd try another

Answer (score 1):

Rather than an Ubuntu related problem, it's probably an issue with your UEFI (or BIOS) configuration. Assuming you can access it before GRUB loads, please check, and if needed, change these settings:

```
BIOS Setup
Integrated Peripherals
Legacy USB Support --> [Enabled]
```

If that does not solve the problem, try following [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/reset-your-ubuntu-password-easily-from-the-live-cd/) walkthrough
so you can at least reset your password.